# Getting unexpected symbol in Pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am using pig to read a file and want to pass those data to a java method and count the records. But I am getting exception, kindly help my why I am getting this exception

```
REGISTER /user/rakeshar/test.jar
DEFINE Test com.msdw.rakesh.Test;
 temperature = LOAD 'NYQ_MWDATA_ge2_fact.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (period_fundmtls_id:int, metric_def_id:int, real_value:double, currency_unit_id:int, observation_type_cd:chararray, non_currency_unit_id:int);
return_val = com.msdw.rakesh.Test(temperature);
DUMP return_val;
```

In the above code I getting error on the 4th line, below is the exception

```
557506 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - Failed to parse: <line 3, column 0>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'return_val'
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:235)
```

Kindly help me out here, as I am new to hadoop and pig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a projection to call such a UDF:

```
return_val = FOREACH temperature GENERATE com.msdw.rakesh.Test(*);
```

If you want to do some operation like the total number of records in `temperature` do

```
X = GROUP temperature ALL;
return_val = FOREACH XGENERATE com.msdw.rakesh.Test(temperature);
```

as you probably know, there is the count function in pig already. also, you need to think about scalability. See here http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch10.html.

Comment: As per my understanding if I do the above you suggested then, the Test will be called for each row, but my need is to pass all the rows collected in the temperature and get the count of row, or any operation like that, is that possible?